# Export from OO Base to M$ Access

Tags: database, ms-access, export-to-csv, openoffice-base

As I understood it can export only in PDF, but i doesn't think that scanning PDF with Fine Reader, saving as text and then exporting to Access is the easiest way. The "Export" tab always inactive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose an export to csv as e.g
here 
http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=5009

The way is from OObase -> Calc -> csv
and csv can be easily read into any database

Comment: another problem => some fields in cyrillic layout ant they exported as "?????????"

Comment: well I guess you have to use some UTF encoding then. Is the stuff exported correcty into the .csv file?